# Why my colorbox looks broken?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, colorbox

[image: broken colorbox]

Hi, this is what I get when I use the colorbox. the image is correctly attached. when I remove the colorbox, the image opens in a window.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: This is web development, colorbox jquery plugin

Comment: got some code to show? also check all the color box files include paths are correct.

Comment: Its a wordpress installation.... and even tried with colorbox plugin.. its coming like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using jQuery 1.4.4+ and that you are loading the CSS prior to the plugin script.

Comment: thanks, i hev noticed that my wordpress 3.3.1 jquery verson is 1.4.1, and when i use 1.7 the plugin works without any problem